# peek help in Productivity Power-Tools plugin for Visual Studio 2013 opens same page every time

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, productivity-power-tools

When I right click on a type, for example `int` and click peek help I am always shown the same page:
[Writing Code in the Code and Text Editor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=en-US&k=k(VS.TextEditor)&k=k(VS.Ambient)&rd=true#content)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'll add that I'm looking for contextual help/documentation for Win32 C++ functions (e.g. `CreateFileW`) in Visual Studio 2017 and have the same problem.  It seems to work for C#.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Custom Web Search Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=appastoy82.CustomWebSearch2) to be a decent replacement for this functionality.  However, it only supports Visual Studio 2017.

I made a custom Google search because the search function on learn.microsoft.com is less than desirable: [https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alearn.microsoft.com+{QUERY}](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alearn.microsoft.com+%7BQUERY%7D), e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Alearn.microsoft.com+CreateFile.